# SVG and EPS with large file size

Tags: matlab, svg, figure

I have a problem related to exporting matlab figures to another formats like .svg and .eps.( this happens sometimes and sometimes tthe exported svg files were excellent.)
When i want to export figures to these extensions, the quality was poor like this
[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKYd0.png),
The export setup
[export setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKLDJ.png)

And here the figure's file https://ufile.io/7ebczq7k
The quality was excellent when i used this print('-painters','-dsvg','Idg Vs ref') or print('-painters','-depsc','Idr_vs_ref'), but here the file size exceeds 100 mb and it's unacceptale.
(N.b, the file is compiled using matlab r2019a).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't see anything here to do with EPS, so I've removed the tag. This sounds to me like matlab is rendering to a bitmap, and then including that in the EPS. Low resolution rendering is poor quality, high resolution is big. That's life really.

Comment: Yes, I know but the other figures ith the same config do didn't exceed 1mb with a good quality. Here https://file.fm/u/pcmu2zagm is the link  of another exported svg fig with only 237kb!

Comment: Its not an EPS so I can't comment, other than to say that perhaps there is something different about the matlab content which means it is not rendered, but drawn as vectors, when exported to SVG. Possibly your original contains something which cannot be natively drawn in SVG. My initial comment, and this one, refer entirely to EPS. For example pretty much any kind of transparency will result in a large image in an EPS file, EPS doesn't support transparency.

Comment: @King_kh: the example svg shows that matlib adds a lot of coordinates/svg commands to to draw a line. The more curvy a graph gets the more drawing points – filesize explodes. Are there any options to lower precision (like floating point precision) or scale to a smaller page size in print options?

Comment: @herrstrietzel Unfortunately, no such option is available.